# Queries interrupted during execution in the Task Server

Tags: marklogic

**Summary**

I use the Task Server to spawn a series of (same) queries, to devide the ingestion of a few thousands documents.  But most queries are interrupted somewhere in the middle of execution.  Any idea why, or how to get more information about it?

**Details**

The main query (an XQuery in QConsole) takes the path of all the files in a directory (a bit more than 9,000).  It creates chunks of 100 paths, and spawn an anonymous XQuery function.  This function calls xdmp:eval-javascript, and passes it the 100 paths to handle them.

The Javascript code evaluated makes some computations, and end up inserting 2 documents.  None of the input file result in inserting document at the same URI.

The Javascript code logs a message "start of chunk #1" (with the sequential number of the chunk) at the beginning, then "end of chunk #1".  The start messages appear a lot of time, but the end message only once per chunk (fortunately).

**Pseudo code**

The main query executed in QConsole (spawing anonymous function, itself evaluating Javascript, ust because it itself imports some SJS libraries):

```
let $files := ...
for $i     in 0 to 92
let $chunk := $files[(($i * 100) + 1) to (($i + 1) * 100)]
return
  xdmp:spawn-function(function() {
    xdmp:eval-javascript("
      declareUpdate();
      xdmp.log(`start of chunk ${i}`);
      for ( const f of chunk ) {
        read file
        insert 2 documents
      }
      xdmp.log(`end of chunk ${i}`);
    ")
  })
```

The logs show something like:

```
start of chunk #9
start of chunk #1
start of chunk #5
start of chunk #4
start of chunk #3
end of chunk #5
start of chunk #7
start of chunk #4     --> again
start of chunk #8
start of chunk #9     --> again
end of chunk #9
start of chunk #8     --> again
start of chunk #7     --> again
start of chunk #2
...
```

As you can see, the same start message appears several times.

**Question**

Any idea what can cause these query interruptions/abortions/restarts?  Or how I can find more information?

Comment: Try setting your **file log level** to `Debug` and see what messages are reported around these transaction restarts.

Comment: Are you getting doc nodes, or uris? And are you getting those in an `eager` way?

Comment: Ah right, the deadlock detection goes to `ErrorLog.txt`, not `TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt`.  Thank you @MadsHansen, I was able to identify it was due to garbage remaining from a previous stage of the project (this is a dev instance).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Making a proper response to my own question, based on @MadsHansen comment.  Thanks!

The trick here is that messages for deadlock detection are output in `ErrorLog.txt` (not in `TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt`, even though I was on the Task Server).

The log level for them is `Info`, which is the default.